# Replace emoticon with word in tweet using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, emoticons

Basically the idea is to map the emoticons in the string to actual words. say for :) you replace it with happy.
A more clear example would be.
Original: 
Today is a sunny day :). But tomorrow it is going to rain :(.
Final:
Today is a sunny day happy. But tomorrow it is going to rain sad.

I have trying a solution using a common regex for all emoticons but I am not sure once you detect it is an emoticon, how to go back and replace each one with appropriate word.
I need it only for three emoticons :),:( and :D. Thank you.

Comment: String.Replace seems to be your ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) method that takes a custom match evaluator.

```
static string ReplaceSmile(Match m) {
    string x = m.ToString();
    if (x.Equals(":)")) {
        return "happy";
    } else if (x.Equals(":(")) {
        return "sad";
    }
    return x;
}

static void Main() {
    string text = "Today is a sunny day :). But tomorrow it is going to rain :(";
    Regex rx = new Regex(@":[()]");
    string result = rx.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceSmile));
    System.Console.WriteLine("result=[" + result + "]");
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. For adding :D i just change the regex to ":[()D]" right ?

Comment: @Vignesh This is correct. Of course you'll need to extend `ReplaceSmile` to accept `:D`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a plain replace? You have just three fixed patterns:

```
str = str.Replace(":(", "text1")
         .Replace(":)", "text2")
         .Replace(":D", "text3")
```

Comment: something where you might have text with :Dexter. For the other two its fine.

Comment: @Vignesh: You will have that problem with any approach (including regex).

Comment: hmm thats true but it is easier in regex to add more conditions as and when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution:

```
var emoticons = new Dictionary<string, string>{ {":)", "happy"}, {":(", "sad"} };
string result = ":) bla :(";
foreach (var emoticon in emoticons)
{
    result = result.Replace(emoticon.Key, emoticon.Value);
}
```

For any additional emoticons that need replacing, just add another key-value-pair, like `{":D", "laughing"}` to the dictionary.

As an alternative to the foreach-loop, it would also be possible (though not necessarily recommended) to use the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) standard query operator:

```
string result = emoticons.Aggregate(":) bla :(",
                (text, emoticon) => text.Replace(emoticon.Key, emoticon.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why regex?

```
 string newTweet = oldTweet
  .Replace(":)","happy")
  .Replace(":(","sad")
  .Replace(":D","even more happy");
```