# Smiley replace in JavaScript with regex

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I just came across the following post [Replace emoticon with word in tweet using regex c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588784/replace-emoticon-with-word-in-tweet-using-regex-c-sharp) where smileys are parsed and replaced with some custom text:

```
static string ReplaceSmile(Match m) {
    string x = m.ToString();
    if (x.Equals(":)")) {
        return "happy";
    } else if (x.Equals(":(")) {
        return "sad";
    }
    return x;
}

static void Main() {
    string text = "Today is a sunny day :). But tomorrow it is going to rain :(";
    Regex rx = new Regex(@":[()]");
    string result = rx.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceSmile));
    System.Console.WriteLine("result=[" + result + "]");
}
```

Can you help me to achieve the same via JavaScript say I have smileys in a string in JavaScript variable, how to achieve the same behavior what we did in C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "hello :)".replace(/:[()]/, "replacement");
```

See the [JavaScript string replacement method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for more details.

In your case I probably wouldn't use regular expressions. I would just do this -

```
var text = "Today is a sunny day :). But tomorrow it is going to rain :(";
text = text.replace(":)", "happy");
text = text.replace(":(", "sad");
// text is "Today is a sunny day happy. But tomorrow it is going to rain sad"
```

Comment: I have multiple if else in my "ReplaceSmile" function. This will replace all the smileys with "replacement"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you don't care to use regex:

```
var happy_replacement = "smile!";
var sad_replacement = "frown...";

var happy_replaced = ":) Sunshine and lollipops".replace(":)",happy_replacement);
var sad_replaced = ":( Snips and snails".replace(":(",sad_replacement);
var both_replaced =
    ":( and :)"
        .replace(":(",sad_replacement)
        .replace(":)",happy_replacement);
```

Edit: A function to do them both.

```
function replace_all(raw) {
    var happy_replacement = "smile!";
    var sad_replacement = "frown...";
    var replaced =
        input
            .replace(":(",sad_replacement)
            .replace(":)",happy_replacement);
    return replaced;
}

var output = replace_all(":) and :(");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "replace" method's overload:

```
var text = "hello :) :(";
var pattern = /:[()]/ig;

text = text.replace(pattern, function (match, p) {
    if (match == ':)') {
        return "happy";
    }
    else if (match == ':(') {
        return "sad";
    } else {
        return match;
    }
});
console.log(text);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JDx53/1/

Comment: might help to have a functioning fiddle

Comment: The output will come in "Console"